# get JList contained in a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist, mouselistener

I have a big panel with 6 JScrollPane inside, each JScrollPane contain a JList.
I am trying to add a MouseListener event to every single JList on the panel, how can i get access to it? to better understand, this is my code:

```
private void agregarDobleClick() {
    for (Component c : jPanel1.getComponents()) {

        c.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
                JList list = (JList) evt.getSource();
                if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    Rectangle r = list.getCellBounds(0, list.getLastVisibleIndex());
                    if (r != null && r.contains(evt.getPoint())) {
                        modCitaPOPUP modcita = new modCitaPOPUP((Cita) list.getSelectedValue());
                        modcita.setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

when i run this, it add the mouseListener to the JScrollPane, and when i double-click on a JList item, nothing happen because the mouseListener event isnt there. 
thanks.

Comment: Add the mouse listeners to the `JList`s when you create them; they are available then and you won't have to go through the trouble of trying to navigate through component trees to get to them.

Comment: It look's like you're trying to hunt sparrows with a 12 Ga shotgun. Sure you'll get a lot of feathers, but not much bird will be left. Rather than trying to add the MouseListener willy-nilly to components on the JPanel, and thus missing the JList, why not have decent references to the JLists themselves, and then add the MouseListener **directly** to the JList references?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *"It look's like you're trying to hunt sparrows with a 12 Ga shotgun"* I know what I'm doing this weekend!

Comment: okay, i was trying to "avoid" writting more lines using the for loop, but i'll do it, thanks.

Comment: @JoseMiguelLedón You've already used a for-loop.  You could keep all the `JList`'s in some kind of array or `List` adding may-be 4 lines of code and change the `for-loop` to access it instead...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It "looks" like, from your description, you're adding the `MouseListener` to the `JScrollPane` and not the `JList`.

The simple solution would be to make a speciality `MouseListener`...

```
public class ListMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
    private JList list;
    public ListMouseListener (JList list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
        // Know you're self out with the list instance variable...
    }
}
```

And apply it to each `JList` when you create it...

```
JList list = new JList();
list.addMouseListener(new ListMouseListener(list));
```

Now, if you're worried that they might be inefficient or consuming to much memory (which based on your example, you're not), you could instead, create a generic `MouseListener` which used the event source to determine who triggered it...

```
public class ListMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
        Object source = evt.getSource();
        if (source instanceof JList) {
            JList list = (JList)source;
        }
    }
}
```

Then create a single instance and apply it all your instances of `JList`...

```
ListMouseListener singleInstance = new ListMouseListener();
//...
JList list = new JList();
list.addMouseListener(singleInstance);
```

Comment: Creating a new instance of the `MouseListener` for each an every `Jlist` will use more memory, yes...

Comment: @JoseMiguelLedón: is memory so precious that you're actually worried about this? Do you have 20,000 JLists? If not, I think you're worrying about the wrong thing. Worry more about correct, debuggable, **functioning** code.

Comment: Yes.  You would have single instance of the `MouseListener` which could be applied to n number of `JList`s which would only increase the memory usage marginal...and you'd have to have a LOT of `JList`s to see it....1 instance as opposed to n instances...